# Glob on mean.js v4.0 does not get module name "resume"

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, glob, meanjs

Using the meanjs.org stack to create a portfolio site.

Created a vertical module named "resume", apparently it changes to "resume**s**" for whatever reason.

Decided to be picky and renamed everything back to "resume". Routing doesn't work. I check the globs, looks like it missed the file entirely but got every other module despite the fact it's in the same folder hierarchy.

It also got all the other sub-folders in the module, i.e. models, services, images, etc. just not the routes.

Changed the modules/resume folder name to random gibberish i.e. "jskdhfkjsdhfkjsd", it detects, changed back to "resume", missing.

Changed to "resumé" and it works.

My config/default.js is this:

```
server: {
    allJS: ['gruntfile.js', 'server.js', 'config/**/*.js', 'modules/*/server/**/*.js'],
    models: 'modules/*/server/models/**/*.js',
    routes: ['modules/*[!core]/server/routes/**/*.js','modules/core/server/routes/**/*.js'],
    sockets: 'modules/*/server/sockets/**/*.js',
    config: 'modules/*/server/config/*.js',
    policies: 'modules/*/server/policies/*.js',
    views: 'modules/*/server/views/*.html'
}
```

So it really should pick up the folder if it's named "resume". The only thing I can think of is that there's something preventing "resume" from being used, i.e. if it's a reserved keyword somewhere.

node.js version v0.10.35.

package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.10.0",
    "express-session": "~1.9.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.1.6",
    "body-parser": "~1.9.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.2",
    "compression": "~1.2.0",
    "method-override": "~2.3.0",
    "morgan": "~1.4.1",
    "multer": "0.1.6",
    "connect-mongo": "~0.4.1",
    "connect-flash": "~0.1.1",
    "helmet": "~0.4.0",
    "consolidate": "~0.10.0",
    "swig": "~1.4.1",
    "mongoose": "~3.8.8",
    "passport": "~0.2.0",
    "passport-local": "~1.0.0",
    "passport-facebook": "~1.0.2",
    "passport-twitter": "~1.0.2",
    "passport-linkedin": "~0.1.3",
    "passport-google-oauth": "~0.1.5",
    "passport-github": "~0.1.5",
    "acl": "~0.4.4",
    "socket.io": "~1.1.0",
    "lodash": "~2.4.1",
    "forever": "~0.11.0",
    "bower": "~1.3.8",
    "grunt-cli": "~0.1.13",
    "chalk": "~0.5.1",
    "glob": "~4.0.5",
    "async": "~0.9.0",
    "nodemailer": "~1.3.0"
},
```

Comment: Sounds to me like you're running headlong into some "Convention over Configuration" issues, though `resumé` is a bit of a puzzler.

Comment: At this point, I'm thinking of just re-creating the module via the yeoman generator-meanjs#v4.0-dev and just grind my teeth when I see "resumes". I know the current v4.0 isn't 100% stable but this is just weird behaviour.

Comment: Also, if I explicitly add 'modules/resume/server/routes/**/*.js' to server.routes in config/default.js, it works =\